# how to redeem Amazon gift cards on a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, amazon, ebook-management, hardware

I currently have some money in my Amazon account purchased through an Amazon gift card and can redeem an additional card through the web interface.  I have redeemed cards directly on the kindle, but that was when prompted because the balance was too low for a purchase.

Where or how can I redeem a gift directly on the Kindle itself?  I've looked through the online store interface and been through the settings.  It's a seventh generation kindle with touchscreen, but not a paperwhite -- it uses e-ink.

I can just redeem through the web interface, but would like to be able to use the Kindle itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the reason you are asking the question is that for some reason you don't have access to the account associated with the device. YOu could probably check with the Amazon people, but I'm pretty sure that the only way to redeem a gift card is via a web browser and only if you have the account holder's login/pass.

Another option is to just wipe it clean and create your own account.

If you have ebooks that you want to add to the device and they are not encrypted with DRM, you can add them via usb.

Comment: I have access and just used a web interface.  I was more curious than anything else, because I know for a fact that gift cards can be redeemed -- but apparently only when the balance to buy a kindle book is insufficient.